# When does Basis Pursuit and LASSO give the same answer?

Tags: compressed-sensing

There are 3 different but related optimization questions that one can frame given a $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n  \times m}$ and constants $\epsilon, \lambda, k > 0$,

- $$\text{argmin}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^m}  \Vert x \Vert_1 s.t \Vert A x - y\Vert \leq \epsilon $$
- $$\text{argmin}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^m}  \Vert Ax - y \Vert^2 + \lambda \Vert x \Vert_1$$
- $$\text{argmin}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^m}  \Vert A x - y\Vert^2 s.t \Vert x \Vert_1 \leq k $$

The second and the third of the above are Lagrangian duals of each other and what are called "LASSO". The first is the ``Basis Pursuit" form of compressed sensing.

Can someone kindly refer me to references/theorems where its proven what are the "iff" conditions for any pair of them to give the same answer and/or "iff" conditions if known for all of them to coincide?

---

As is usual feel free to assume that $y = Ax^* + \xi$ for some sparse $x^* \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and maybe some norm of $\xi$ is being assumed to be small.  Often its in these noisily realizable cases that answers like the above are easier to give.

And in this noisy realizable setting as above I can find one key theorem about a sufficient condition guaranteeing when is LASSO a near-exact recovery algorithm and that is as given in Theorem 1.12 (page 37) of this review paper, http://www.ecs.umass.edu/~mduarte/images/IntroCS.pdf (...wonder why the authors here do not use the term LASSO in this context although their equation 1.15 is just that..)

One can see Theorem 1.9 (page 32) of the same review above for a sufficient condition when BP is a near-exact recovery algorithm for a similar noisily realizable condition.

And even in this limited setting one can see that there is a somewhat of a gap between these two theorems. I wonder how far this has been or can be closed.